# Appcelerator Titanium JS - Is it possible to create the native iOS 7 sharing dialog and experience?

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

I was a little disappointed that there seems to be no mention of native iOS7 sharing controls with Titanium, as pictured below. And an internet search only turned up a custom solution called [social](https://github.com/aaronksaunders/test_social), which opens a web view to authorise.

Am I missing it or can this not be done with Titanium?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native Sharing module iOS

https://github.com/viezel/TiSocial.Framework

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, it says iOS6+, so I am guessing that it will automatically work and look native on iOS7?

Comment: Yes try it and let me know the result

Comment: Thank you Wahhab_mirza, it works perfectly. I did have some trouble installing as I'm new to modules, but I got some help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771409/cannot-get-module-to-work-in-titanium-alloy-js/

Comment: when sharing facebook on ios text + image only image appear , any idea ?

Comment: Please use the example given in app and it should be good to go