# Cannot get module to work in Titanium Alloy JS

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

I've tried to add the [TiSocial.Framework module](https://github.com/viezel/TiSocial.Framework) into Titanium Alloy, and after reading several guides and questions, I still can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Here are the steps I took:

1. Copied the unzipped module files into `modules/iphone/TiSocial.Framework-master`
2. Edited the TiApp.xml file with: `<module platform="iphone">TiSocial.Framework-master</module>`
3. Cleaned the build tried to run the app.

But I get the following error(s):

> Could not find Titanium module id=TiSocial.Framework-master
>   version=latest platform=iphone deploy-type=development
>
> Could not find all required Titanium Modules: id: TiSocial.Framework-master    version:
>   latest     platform: iphone    deploy-type: development

I can't spot where I'm going wrong, in my TiApp.xml Overview screen, I the module appears to be installed just fine (see picture):

[image]

My addition to TiApp.xml looks like this:

```
<modules>
    <module platform="iphone">TiSocial.Framework-master</module>
</modules>
```

I also tried doing the same as above but changing the name of the module, to `dk.napp.social`, because in the README on [their GitHub account](https://github.com/viezel/TiSocial.Framework), it says to reference that in the TiApp.xml. So I tried that but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TiSocial.Framework-master is not the name of the module, also you are not supposed to unzip the entire module plus souurce code and documentation into your modules/ folder, you ONLY want the compiled module binary.

Instead do this:

1. Inside Titanium Studio goto "Help->Install Mobile Module"
2. Enter this url: https://github.com/viezel/TiSocial.Framework/blob/master/dist/dk.napp.social-iphone-1.7.3.zip?raw=true
3. Choose your project, hit ok, and it should be installed now.

Comment: Thanks! Do modules always have their compiled module binary in the `dist` directory? Also, what is the convention for finding out the correct name of the module?

Comment: Not always, but many / most open source modules do put that there. The best way to find out is to read the README or if in doubt read the [`manifest`](https://github.com/viezel/TiSocial.Framework/blob/master/manifest) file and look for `moduleid`.

Comment: latest version is 1.8.2 so use https://github.com/viezel/TiSocial.Framework/blob/master/dist/dk.napp.social-iphone-1.8.2.zip?raw=true maybe there's an automatic way to get latest?

Comment: when sharing facebook on ios text + image only image appear , any idea ?