# Can a Titanium app access the ios share features?

Tags: javascript, ios, social-networking, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

I want to let user's of my app share stuff by clicking on a share icon and bringing up the ios share page that pops up from the bottom of the screen and shows share options including message, mail, twitter, and facebook. I notice that apps, including the BBC News app have share icons that do this but I can't find anywhere that says how to do this with a Titanium app.

Is it possible? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this widget which brings up the native share sheet: https://github.com/ricardoalcocer/socialshare

Comment: This is exactly what I am after but unfortunately require the TiSocial.Framework module which gives me build errors.

Comment: I'm using it like this:
<module platform="iphone" version="1.7.10">dk.napp.social</module>

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes it was a version problem and all works well now. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try out this one: https://github.com/viezel/TiSocial.Framework

It works for iOS6, iOS7 and iOS8 as long as your app uses the Titanium SDK 3.4.0 or above.

It is also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757192/appcelerator-titanium-js-is-it-possible-to-create-the-native-ios-7-sharing-dia).

Comment: It looks to be what I want but unfortunately I get a build error when including that module so can't try it out.

Comment: You could post a new question concerning this error

Comment: It was a version thing. Now fixed. All works fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could write your own module using this guide https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/iOS+Module+Development+Guide

Comment: Link only answers, although they may answer the question, can become irrelevant with time; [See this article about how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer):  "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. _Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline_."